# Database connection not workinh

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database, phpmyadmin

I am not able to connect to my database. db info: dbname: users, dbtable; user.

I keep getting an error, and dont know how to fix it.

The error I am getting is:

> I will enter it here with an edit.

It should be working since i added all the deeden refrences ( i think?) and had a working connection when i configured the database.

here's my code:

(beginners code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace hpjct
{

public partial class _Default : Page
{
    private string conn;
    MySqlConnection connect;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string user = username.Text;
        string pass = password.Text;

        if (user == "" || pass == "")
        {
            lbmsg.Text = "Please fill in all information";
            lbmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            return;
        }
        bool r = validate_login(user, pass);

        if (r)
        {
            lbmsg.Text = "Correct";
        }
        else
        {
            lbmsg.Text = "False";
        }
    }

    private void db_connection()
    {
        try
        {
            conn = "Server=localost;Database=users;Uid=root;Pwd=;";
            connect = new MySqlConnection(conn);
            connect.Open();
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    private bool validate_login(string user, string pass)
    {
        db_connection();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username=@username AND password=@password ";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", pass);
        cmd.Connection = connect;
        MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (login.Read())
        {
            connect.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            connect.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Thx in advance!

Comment: What's the error that you are getting?

Comment: Yeah we need that information. Also, you are using a value for password, right? Yes - it's good that you took it out for posting, but you are using one in your actual code, yes?

Comment: There, I stubbed it out for you Tjazz. Fill in the blanks above. Click [edit]

Comment: Thanks all!    I have included a schreenshot of the error within visual studio ->  http://prnt.sc/chitnd  . Also, i dont use a password, so thats why its blank. Drew, What do you mean? (im new to stacks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! Just use this:

```
"Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;P‌​wd=myPassword;"
```